# Xcode schemes are lost while copying the source folder to another computer

Tags: xcode

This is probably something simple. I have created 3 special schemes for building my project in Xcode:

[image]

When I moved the entire project folder to another computer, installed Xcode and opened the same project, there was only one scheme:

[image]

How do I copy all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to "share" the schemes before the transfer. Do that for each scheme individually, and *then* do the transfer.

[image]

Comment: Xcode just doesn't stop surprising me. Why would someone not want to include them in a project directory. (Rhetorical question.)

Comment: Insufficient info to answer. You said "When I moved the entire project folder to another computer" but you did not explain _how_ you moved the folder.

Comment: Copy-and-paste type move. How else would you do it?

Comment: Did your username change across the computers?

Comment: Yes it did......

Comment: There you go. If a scheme is not "shared", it is filed under your username. That username is not present on the new machine. Perhaps we could have solved the problem by digging into the project and changing the username that the scheme is filed under. Open the project file with Show Package Contents and try it. You'll see what I mean. :)

Comment: So the point is, the schemes _did_ travel with the project onto the new computer, but they were not applicable to the username on that computer so they did not appear in Xcode.

Comment: First off, your original suggestion helped. So there's no need to do anything else. It was just that silly checkbox that I commented about. Secondly, it would've been even dumber UI (than the Xcode currently is) if they tied it up to a user name. Luckily they did not.